# SQL Server Import Character Encoding Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, character-encoding

So I am doing a SQL Import via Sql Server Import and Export Wizard with an Excel spread sheet and the following happens:

`Veubroncé`  comes in as `Veubroncã‰`

Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when UTF-8 encoded text is interpreted as ANSI encoded text. Are you sure you're not importing a CSV text file rather than Excel? Open the CSV file in Notepad and change the encoding to "UTF-8 with signature".